# string.Join(string, string[]) returns "System.String[]"

Tags: c#, arrays

I need some help. I have a method that should output a txt file with the contents of a list(each item on a line). The list items are string arrays. The problem is that when I call `string.Join` it returns the literal string `"System.String[]"` instead of the actual concatenated string. I watched it in the debugger and the list and its arrays have the correct strings. Any idea how I can get the actual string so it can be written in the txt file?

Here is my code :

```
 public void myMethod()
    {
        List<Array> list = new List<Array>();
        for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] linie = new string[3];
            linie[0] = myGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            linie[1] = myGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            linie[2] = myGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

            {
                list.Add(linie);
            }
        }
        string path = "S:\\file.txt";
        StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
        foreach (Array x in list)
        {
            string s = string.Join(",", x);
            file.WriteLine(s);
        }
            file.Close();
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `string.Concat(",", x)`?

Comment: @gwin003: That won't help.

Comment: "SystemString[] " is the actual string that it returns.

Comment: Why are you defining list as List<Array> instead of List<string[]>?  I'm guessing that it is getting confused and using the LINQ join method (which joins generic arrays together into another array) instead of the string.join method, which joints string arrays together into a single string.

Comment: change all uses of `Array` to `string[]` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`string.Join()` takes a `params object[]`.

When you pass a variable of compile-time type `Array`, it interprets that as a single item in the array, and it ends up passing `new object[] { yourArray }`.
It then calls `ToString()` on the single item, which returns the type name (since arrays do not override `ToString()`.

To fix that, you need to change `Array` to any strongly-typed collection type (`string[]`, `object[]`, or `IEnumerable<string>`).
It will then pass the array itself to `Join()`, instead of assuming it's a single parameter in the paramarray.

Comment: Kudos on actually understanding the real question. Formatting in the question could've saved that hehe. +1 from me.

Comment: @Niels: I completely misunderstood the problem.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Lol, confusion all around. I'll edit the question a bit to clarify.

Comment: The general lesson is to avoid the use of `Array`.

Comment: Thank you SLaks and others for the answers. I'll mark this as the answer. And thank you Niels for clarifying the question.

Answer (score 3):

Change the type of

```
List<Array> list = new List<Array>();
```

to

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
```

You can use [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx).

```
string[] contents = list.Select(a => string.Join(",", a)).ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(path, contents);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the *reason* you're getting those results:

The overloads for string.Join are:

```
Join(string, params object[])
Join(string, params string[])
Join(string, params string[], int, int)
Join(string, IEnumerable<string>)
Join<T>(string, IEnumerable<string>)
```

Since your second parameter to `string.Join` is an untyped `Array`, which is neither a `string[]` nor an `IEnumerable<T>`, the "best" overload is `Join(string, params object[])`, with the `Array` treated an an `object[]` with a single value - the `Array` (not an `object[]` with several `string` or `object` values).  So Join calls `ToString()` on the `Array`, which returns `System.String[]` since that is the actula *type* of the Array.

There are multiple ways to fix it, but to me the  cleanest is to use `List<string[]>` instead of `List<Array>` since you only ever store strings in the array.  That way the overload 'Join(string, string[])` will be called which gives you the results you expect:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] linie = new string[3];
        linie[0] = myGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        linie[1] = myGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        linie[2] = myGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

        {
            list.Add(linie);
        }
    }
    string path = "S:\\file.txt";
    StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
    foreach (string[] x in list)
    {
        string s = string.Join(",", x);
        file.WriteLine(s);
    }
        file.Close();
}
```